# How to use FFMPEG on wowza to encode Live rtmp streams?

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, live, rtmp, wowza

I am looking for a source to explain how to use FFmpeg with wowza to transcode live rtmp to http. Does anyone know anything about it or know where to point me to get some info?

Thank you all,

Answer (score 0):

Wowza does not currently support live transcoding of video, however, transcoding is **only** necessary when you need to create new video data. As long as you are outputting the bitrate/resolutions that you need wowza can re-package to most protocals you may need for internet delivery.

Example:

```
3 H.264 streams in an RTMP container --> WOWZA ---> 3 RTMP streams
                                               ---> 3 Apple HLS streams (http)
                                               ---> 3 Silverlight smooth streams (http)
```

Quickstart Guide [Here](http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/content.php?3-quick-start-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Wowza V3 (released in October 2011) has transcoding capabilities. It sounds like you're really just trying to rewrap the H.264 RTMP steam into Apple HLS, which doesn't require any transcoding, just segmenting into HTTP packets.